# how to change disk size? unallocated disk

Tags: 14.04, steam, disk-management, unallocated

[disk details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBRaW.png)

Hello, I wanted to install a D.O.T.A game using steam but I can only install it in /Dev/sda5. I want to either increase the size of the disk or make downloads and use the other disk. i cant use all the disk space. I can only us the /Dev/sda5 disk. I cant do anything with /Dev/sda3. its a dead space
please help. I am new to Ubuntu 15.i have included a screen shot so please have a look.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `gparted` for shrinking and expanding partition sizes, however since you'd be editing the `/` folder (what i got from the info you've given) you should do it while booting from Ubuntu Live USB.